# How to save my current location in Google Maps or Google+ Android's app

Tags: google-plus, google-maps, android

I used to have some app that would find my car, but now what I do is use Google+ and "Check In" wherever my car is at, or whenever I just want to remember a location (a friends house, etc...) and select at the bottom of the list "Add new location" (or something like that) since this is not a restaurant or any other public place.

I'm sure this is not the way this was meant to be used but it works. I wonder if there is another explicit way to do this with Google+ or Google Maps. I think is very silly that they don't add this feature since it's almost already fully implemented.

I can't find a way to save custom locations to my favorite locations either. Can't find this kind of feature in Google Maps either. I also don't want to install a new app unless is some kind of Google Maps addon, since I already can do this with Google+ the way I described above.

Comment: This is rather an [android.se] question, isn't it?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an Android application rather than a Web Application.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Maps you can star places. That's how I would do it.

Just tab your current location and mark the place with a star.

When navigating back, you'll see the star on the map, or you can select it as a navigation destination

Comment: Yes! This is exactly what I was looking for. I just couldn't see that little gray star at the top right.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a navigation shortcut and give it a name like "Home", "Office" or "Aunt Tilley". It will be a separate icon that you can then click for instant directions. Then you can drag all your navigation shortcuts into a folder you create and you have a complete custom system.

To create the navigation shortcut:

- long click an empty spot on your page
- choose 'shortcut'
- choose 'Directions and Navigation'
- enter the address
- enter the shortcut name
- click 'save'

Answer (score 0):

Just download trip planner navigation in google play and save multiple locations.

Comment: Could you be more specific, about what programm to download?